# Detect type of region when a key pressed event occurs in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keyevent

I am creating a shortcut in my Java application. When a user hits G, a dialog pops up. However, I do not want this to happen when the user is typing in a text field. Is there a way I can detect the type of region when an key released event occurs so I can only make the dialog window popup when the user is not in a text field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html might be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Window.getFocusOwner() to get the Component that has focus in your application, and then use an instanceof check.

For instance:

```
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G && !(myWindow.getFocusOwner() instanceof TextField))
        {
            showDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this really necessary ? The textfield should just consume the 'G', and the fact the 'G' is typed should only reach your dialog code when not consumed by anything else. With those keybindings as suggested by AKJ this should be possible